# ejabberd: inspect Mnesia tables?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I'm digging into ejabberd but I can't find a way to inspect its Mnesia tables.

Is there something like the MySQL shell to inspect tables?

Comment: I've found ./ejabberdctl dump <FILENAME> to dump the database contents into a file, but not an easy way to select data (through a shell for ex.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use the Table Visualizer, in module [`tv`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tv/table_visualizer.html).

It can help examine `ets` tables and `mnesia` tables. You can simply start it on any connected node (e.g. with "ejabberdctl debug"), with:

```
 tv:start().
```

Answer (score 2):

Just go to folder where ejabberd is installed.Then go to bin folder and type command ./ejabberdctl dump_table file_name_in_which_table_will_be_dumped Table_Name.

This file will be created in database/ejabberd@localhost/dump_table file_name_in_which_table_will_be_dumped